# If two linear differential equations have matrices who have the same eigenvalues, are they topologically equivalent?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have two differential equations

$\displaystyle \frac{dX}{dt}=AX$ and

$\displaystyle \frac{dY}{dt}=CY$

If $A$ and $C$ have the same eigenvalues, are they topologically equivalent?

Comment: What does "topologically equivalent" mean?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: It refers to the (flows of) the ODEs rather than to the matrices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy#Topological_equivalence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $C$ have the same Jordan canonical form (in particular if they have distinct eigenvalues and those are the same for both) then they are similar: there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A = S C S^{-1}$.  Then $X$ satisfies $\dfrac{dX}{dt} = A X$ if and only if $Y = S^{-1} X$ satisfies $\dfrac{dY}{dt} = C Y$.

Comment: And if they don't have the same Jordan form, but merely the same eigenvalues?

Comment: Then they are not similar.